# Install TeX on a shared drive

Tags: installing

I have several computers and I don't want to replicate the installation.

Is it possible to install MikTeX (for instance) on a shared drive and call the binary file from any computer to compile the LaTeX code?

Comment: Would MiKTeX portable work? http://miktex.org/portable/about

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: It would be good to know what operating system do the computers run.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how easy it is with MiKTeX (you could try the portable version as suggested in one of the comments) but TeX Live installation to a network drive is a popular solution to share TeX between different PCs, even with different operating systems.  There are even convenience scripts ([w32cilent](http://www.tug.org/texlive/w32client.html)) to help integrate such installations into client systems (Windows only), as suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22362/how-to-mirror-texlive/22367#22367).

Comment: We dumped MiKTeX for TeX Live some years ago (2007?) for exactly this reason. The current release may be better, but I've had no reason to experiment.