# “xelatex: Command not found.” on network installation

Tags: xetex, errors, texlive, mactex, texshop

I installed a TeX Live 2011 distribution on a network drive, actually an Apple Time Capsule. Even though normal TeXing with LaTeX (via `pdfTeX`) in TeXShop works fine, when I try to use the `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex` option, I only get the `xelatex: Command not found.` error in the console.

This is what I have entered in TeXShop to be the (pdf)TeX path:

```
/Volumes/Time Capsule/TeX Live/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin/
```

A `ls -l` of this directory returns the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx@ 1 username  staff         5 23 Oct 17:00 xelatex -> xetex
-rwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff  17777824 22 Jun 00:11 xetex
```

But also changing the typesetting option to `%!TEX TS-program = xetex` is to no avail, as it gives me the error `xetex: Command not found.`

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you try protecting the spaces? `/Volumes/Time\ Capsule/TeX\ Live/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method used by MacTeX is to build a symbolic link to the directory containing the binaries. You can try the same strategy: from the Terminal issue the following commands

```
sudo ln -s "/Volumes/Time Capsule/TeX Live/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin" /usr/texbin
echo "/usr/texbin" > TeX
sudo mv TeX /etc/paths.d
```

In this way you can put into the preferences of TeXShop simply the path `/usr/texbin`. The second and third line will make available `/usr/texbin` also for all other applications (the Terminal, for instance).

This has another advantage; when TeX Live 2012 will be available, all you'll have to do, after installing it, will be

```
sudo rm /usr/texbin
sudo ln -s "/Volumes/Time Capsule/TeX Live/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin" /usr/texbin
```

and the new binaries will be available to all programs without any other intervention.

You may want to choose a different name than `texbin`, if you intend to try MacTeX, that would overwrite that symbolic link. But reinstating it is simply a matter of repeating that command at the Terminal.

Note also that this procedure doesn't touch anything in the system: the former state can be obtained by simply removing the symbolic link and the added file:

```
sudo rm /usr/texbin
sudo rm /etc/paths.d/TeX
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies within the specifics of my installation as I installed TeXLive to the NAS and just the “GUI-Applications.pkg” from the MacTeX bundle to my local machine.

So it is actually more a TeXShop-related problem rather than a MacTeX problem because it turns out that TeXShop uses the path set in its preferences exactly for what it is labelled: (pdf)TeX. The problem with this is that it *only* uses it for (pdf)TeX. All other so-called TeXShop Engines are stored separately in the user Library (`~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/`). The XeLaTeX engine for example looks like this:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
xelatex  -file-line-error -synctex=1 "$1"
```

This means that it searches for the `xelatex` program in the system `PATH` and the standard `bin`s of a local installation exclusively.

To solve this problem, I need to either add the remote `texbin` to my system `PATH` as pointed out by *egreg* (thank you for that) or add it manually to all TeXShop engines. If done the latter way, one has to escape the spaces like this `/Volumes/Time\ Capsule/TeX\ Live/2011/bin/x86_64-darwin`, of course, as said by *egreg* as well.